# Having difficulties in assinging Type for useContext in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, use-context

I am using useContext for authentication purposes and my code is of below

```
type userSignup = {
name: string;
email: string;
password: string;
signup() => void;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<userSignup|null>(null);

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) =>{
const signup = async (name,email,password) => {

const DTO ={name:name, email:email:, password:password}


const response = await fetch('url',DTO);
const data = await response.json();

setToken(data);


}
}

return (
<AuthContext.Provider value={{signup}}> {children} </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

The issue is an error appears telling me that type (name: string, email: string,password: string, signup() => Promise) is not assignable to type userSignup.

I can overcome this by changing the

```
export const AuthContext = createContext<any|null>(null);
```

but I don't think using `any` is a good approach.

Could someone please suggest a better solution for this?
Thank you in advance

//UPDATE 1

As David Alvarez suggested. I have changed the type userSignUp into:

```
type userSignUp ={ 
name: string;
email: string;
password: password;
signup: () => Promise<void>;
}
```

Now the error message says:
`Type'(name:any, email:any, password:any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '()=> Promise<void>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the compiler error :) `signup() => Promise` is not assignable to `signup() => void`.

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value):

> RETURN TYPE:  A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the **async** function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the async function.

Change your type from

```
type userSignup = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  signup() => void;
}
```

to

```
type userSignup = (name: string, email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
```

And it should work.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. I just did that, now slightly different error message. It now shows: Type'(name:any, email:any, password:any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type ()=> Promise<void>

Comment: @Vincensiu Thanks I didn't see the type was also wrong. I updated my answer and this should work

Comment: Because you only pass the signup function, the type of the Context should be the type of the function

Comment: Thanks David. It just change the error message from one to another. Now it says: Type {signup:(name:any, email:any, password:any) => Promise<void> is missing the following properties from type 'userSignUp': name, email, password

Comment: @Vincensiu I think it is because you still have `()` instead of `(name: string, email: string, password: string)`. Can you refresh the page (I edited my answer multiple times before) and check you got the parameters in the type ?

Comment: It works now. Thank David. Sorry I had network issue, your edited post didn't update earlier haha. Thanks so much. Appreciate it.